# How do I solve the System.IO.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to load a picture in MonoGame (without Content.Load), But when I try to launch the project I encounter the **System.IO.FileNotFoundException** and I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**Error message:** System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'G:\Min enhet\C#\FirstMonoGameProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Content\Graphic\CoolBox'.'

***The code where I get the error***

```
 public Texture2D LoadTexture()
        {

   
            string fullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
            + "/Content/Graphic/" + "CoolBox";


            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(fullPath, FileMode.Open))
            {

                Texture2D myTexture2D = Texture2D.FromStream(EntityManager.graphicsDevice, fileStream);
                return myTexture2D;

            }

        }
```

***Additional code where I call on the method** (both from game1)*

```
 protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
           
            coolBox.LoadTexture();

        }
```

---

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

        spriteBatch.Draw(coolBox.LoadTexture(), new Rectangle(0, 0, 280, 210), Color.White);

        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: Obviously the name of the path and/or file is wrong. Doesn't the file has an extension like .gif, .png, .jpg ?

Comment: Just check if the filepath on your Windows machine exists. And here is also a pro tip: Don't use special characters in a filepath. The system allows it, but this can cause troubles. Rename "C#" to "CSharp" or whatever you like.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Calling `CoolBox.LoadTexture()` in Draw will reload the texture from disk every time draw is called.  This will add blocking time to the draw method.  Returning a reference from a method is not great but OK, Loading from disk every call is not. There is no possibility of caching the texture on the gpu.

Answer (score 1):

First I would add checking for the file existence using
`File.Exists(String)` method.
Also I found helpful is to use `Path.Combine()` method to properly create a path instead of manually concatenating strings.

Answer (score 1):

System.IO.FileNotFoundException appears when the path that you are using is wrong , it means that the file doesnt exist.
Your problem cames on the variable string fullpath wich has a wrong path.

First check on your computer(windows search : windows+s) that the file exists by copying there the full path.
Anyway to prevent this exception you can use try catch block to display a message if the file dont exists.
Other solution can be using File.Exists(path) , this way you dont throw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Also check your actual file name. When you go to the properties of the file and the name is called lets say `test.txt` then the actual file name is `test.txt.txt`. When creating a file through the explorer for example write always the name without the extension. Just if it helps someone else

Comment: This can really be helpful, since windows configuration hides the extension. I was getting the exception and didn't understand why, it was because my xml file was really xml.txt